# Shirakawa, Japan — Where's designated photo spot looking over village hovels and grass?

Tags: japan, identify-this

I saw on [r/Breath_of_the_Wild](https://redd.it/8etkup). I already tried Google Reverse Image Search. I don't want just fish, but teach me how to fish! If you never went here, pls expound how you located.

1. Where's "designated "photo spot"" written in this [r/villageporn comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/VillagePorn/comments/8ewkvt/shirakawa_japan/dxzfqu7/)?

> As someone who lived in Japan? Annoyed.  There's clearly a **designated "photo spot"** because this exact photo at this exact angle is posted by every single person.  It's like the leaning tower of Pisa of Japan.
>
> Also the village is kept this way specifically for villageporn, so it's a bit fake honestly.  It's kind of like taking a picture in an outdoor museum.  There are tons of small towns in Japan that are picturesque but not staged.

2. And "hovel" isn't right word - let me know what is!
3. Can I drive to this look out and just step out car? I don't want to hike!

[image]

Comment: Instead of "hovels", there's a perfectly ordinary word that seems to fit these buildings just fine: "houses".

Comment: @NateEldredge To be quite precise, they're *minka* farmhouses in the *gasshou-zukuri* style, which is found almost exclusively in the Shirakawa area: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minka

Comment: I recently saw a very similar photo on CNN Travel's [16 Japan experiences every traveler needs to enjoy](https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/japan-top-experiences/index.html). See photo 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This view is of the [Gassho no Sato](http://gero-gassho.jp/lg_en/gassho/) portion of the [Gero Onsen Gassho-mura](http://gero-gassho.jp/lg_en/) folk village. This is, as the quote in your question mentions, *quite literally* an outdoor museum.

> At Gero Onsen Gassho-mura, 10 gassho-zukuri (thatched) houses have been transferred from places like Shirakawa-go to form a precious outdoor museum which recreates a mountain settlement from former times, and offers a glimpse into what life might have been like for its inhabitants.

To find this, I loaded Google Earth, went to Shirakawa, found a portion of the town that looks like the following (with all the indications of photos taken in that area), and started reading photo descriptions. From there the links to Gero Onsen Gassho-mura are clear.

[image: Shirakawa-go]